# If a system of equations has solution over $\mathbb{C}$ then does it have solution over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, determinant

My question asks me to prove that if a homogenous system of equations has a non-trivial solution over $\mathbb{C}$, and the matrix has coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}$, then it has a non-trivial solution over $\mathbb{Q}$ .

My attempt: Since the matrix has a non-trivial then the $\det(A) =0$ so it is an $m \times n$ matrix.If the matrix has a complex solution say $a+ib$ where $a \ne 0$ then $a$ must also be a solution to the system (This is something I feel although I have not been able to prove this). However, if the system has a solution of the form $ib$ then how can we say that the system of linear equations has solutions over $\mathbb{R}$, or over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Another argument that I feel should be used over here is that if the matrix $A$ has $\det(A)=0$ then it must have a non-trivial solution over the same field in this case it is over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I need some insight into the problem. Also the generalization of the problem. Some hints would do instead of posting the whole solution.

Comment: What are the assumptions on the matrix? Also taking det of a non-square matrix is kind of forbidden.

Comment: Why should the existence of a non-trivial solution imply that the determinant is zero? Why does determinant being zero imply that the matrix is $m\times n$? Think about how an $m\times n$ system is solved without using the determinant - first Gaussian elimination is preformed until reduced row echelon form (RREF) is reached. How does RREF look like? Since you're only multiplying/dividing and subtracting/adding rationals, it will have only rational entries, with some rows possibly being $0$. What does that say about the solutions?

Comment: Try showing that the conjugate of a solution is a solution. And (though you don't explicitly state it) the system is linear and homogeneous and these are useful facts.